# Creating IJob is failing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 2018.3.14. I am trying to create an `IJob`.

Here is how I call the new job:

```
var Job = new IncomingDataTCPJob
{
    worldServer = this,
    data = sdata
};

JobHandle handle = Job.Schedule();
handle.Complete();
```

`sdata` is string, `worldServer` is instance of class.

Here is my declared `struct`:

```
public struct IncomingDataTCPJob : IJob
{
    public string data;
    public ClientWorldServer worldServer;

    public void Execute()
    {
        worldServer.OnIncomingData(data);
    }
}
```

When I try to run I got this error:

> InvalidOperationException: IncomingDataTCPJob.data is not a value type. Job structs may not contain any reference types.

Any idea why I get this error? I am really very new to Unity's Job system.

Comment: structs are evidentially not allowed to Implement Interfaces*. Why are you not using class instaed of struct? | * I admit, I am confused about this myself. I definitely see Interfacwes on the built-in structs.

Comment: Structs are required for Unity's Jobs system @Christopher

Comment: Can you please provide your ClientWorldServer class definition?

Comment: @ErikOverflow do you need the whole class? It is a big one :)

Comment: Does it inherit from monobehaviour? @VenelinVasilev

Comment: Yes it does `public class ClientWorldServer : MonoBehaviour` :)

Comment: @ErikOverflow the whole class can be seen here: https://pastebin.com/E5V3uvf9

Comment: Jobs get compiled to native code via Burst, so a lot of things that are just fine in a `MonoBehavior` aren't valid in a job. The HPC# system has some pretty severe restrictions, allowing them to get C++-level performance without most of the C++ headaches. I suggest reading through Unity's documentation and blogs on jobs, ECS, Burst, etc. There's a lot of great, well-written information available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jobs cannot receive data that is not blittable.

[According to the Jobs Safety documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JobSystemSafetySystem.html):

> The way the C# Job System copies data means that a job can only access blittable data types.

This is done to avoid race conditions like parallel threads trying to access the same memory reference.

I do not know why you're getting an error on your "string data" field, but it is likely a red herring. Unity's job system cannot interact with reference type elements. Aside from the TransformAccessArray (or other specialized classes), the jobs system can only be used to parallel process raw data. **You cannot pass the custom "WorldClientServer" class to your job struct because it is not primitive** (and therefore not blittable). You will need to convert everything to raw data prior to sending it to the job and convert it back to its referenced object in order to leverage the Jobs system.

The recommended way to get data back from your job is to use a [NativeQueue or other NativeContainer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JobSystemNativeContainer.html) (which are threadsafe). The Jobs system is much more restricted than standard threading, but protects you as a developer from causing nightmare-level race condition bugs and memory leaks.

Comment: Insude the `Execute` of the job can I run for example `Debug.Log` ?

Comment: Not during normal operations, but there is a Run function that you can leverage. You can run a job on the main thread to be able to Debug it. @VenelinVasilev https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Unity.Jobs.IJobExtensions.Run.html

Comment: Debugging adds some flexiblity to jobs that's not allowed in a build, but it's not infinitely flexible. A good rule of thumb is to avoid calling "normal" managed code from anything that gets compiled to native.

Comment: string is a reference type too thats why he get there the error too

Comment: Strings are actually a bit funkier according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/blittable-and-non-blittable-types so there might be a way to pass a string as blittable.@Menyus